# Not able to delete multiple campaigns using Postman from Eloqua

Tags: postman, eloqua

I have been trying to delete multiple campaigns from Eloqua at a time using Postman. But I am not able to do. I don't see reference in the tool as well http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/RESTAPI/REST-API.htm%3FTocPath%3D%2520Application%2520API%7C_____0.

Please let me know if deleting the multiple campaigns is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible.

The link you provided mentions it's outdated, and a redirection link was available: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/rest-endpoints.html

Have a look at all the DELETE methods over there, and you will see that there is no provision for sending more than one `id` at a time.

**Edit:** You say you are using Postman. It is possible to perform repetitive tasks (like deleting mulitple campaigns) with different parameters each time by using [Collections](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/starting_a_collection_run).

**Edit 2:**

- Create an [environment](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments),
- Type your url with the id as a [variable](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables), e.g.: xyz.com/delete/{id}
- And send all the id values as a [JSON or CSV file](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/?_ga=2.102082115.354688799.1507307169-2049272558.1501862758). They have given a sample JSON, you would simply have to provide your ids inside an array, e.g.:

  ```
  [
  {"id":1},
  {"id":2},
  {"id":3}
  ]
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have gone through Collections and dint understand how to delete multiple campaigns at a time. Do you have any example?

Comment: This sounds like a possible solution. Will try. Thank you so much.